# getting user input into a class statically in C++

Tags: c++, oop

I have a large simulation written in C++. The main working unit for the simulation is a class that represents neurons. To do its calculations, each instance of the neuron class needs access to the temperature. Each simulation uses tens of thousands of instances of the neuron class and the temperature is the same value for each neuron. For this reason, I would rather not have it be stored as regular member data, so each instance of the neuron class doesn't have to take up memory storing its own copy. I would ideally store it as a static member variable (or, as a last resort, a global variable). However, I need the temperature to be determined at run-time as user input. Is there any simple way to give the neruon class access to this variable in the manner of static member data?

Comment: Why couldn't you just update the static field in your neuron class when the user inputs a value for the temperature?

Comment: Could you pass `temperature` as a parameter to calculations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because a variable is static, doesn't mean that it also needs to be const. See the below code.

```
#include <cassert>

struct X {
    int member;
    static int static_var;
};

int X::static_var;

int main() {
    X x;
    x.member = 1;
    x.static_var = 2;

    X y;
    y.member = 3;
    y.static_var = 4;

    X::static_var = 5;

    assert(x.static_var == y.static_var);
    assert(&x.static_var == &y.static_var);
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thanks! My OOP chops are a work in progress and the reference I have didn't cover this. Thanks again!

Comment: @cipher, please remember to *accept* an answer if it answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

Just provide a `static` member function, which you can call at runtime and set the temperature member.
Alternatively, You could just make the `static` member `public` and set it directly, As a personal choice I prefer doing it through member function though.

```
class Neuron
{
    public:
        static void setTemperature(int i)
        {
            mTemp = i; 
        }

    private:
        static int mTemp;
};

int Neuron::mTemp = 0;


int main()
{
    //Get Temperature at run-time 
    Neuron::setTemperature(10);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see something like this as a good candidate for a global. What if you add something to your simulation that also uses the temperature?

Since a global variable could be modified by anyone at any time, I suppose the best solution IMO is to have a globally-scoped (standard) function like `getTemperature()`. Then any object could call it at any time. Putting it in its own C file and marking it static makes it only accessible through a mechanism you choose.

Also alternatively, if one doesn't like that, would be to create a static `Globals`or `SimulationInputs` class, with getters for things just like temperature.

Answer (score 0):

Singleton, global, static data, oh my!

The data model for C++ allows us to have global access to data, and to restrict the number of instances of that data, through various mechanisms and hacks.

Just because we can, though, doesn't mean we should. And just because you have a design where it could be a solution, doesn't mean you should choose it.

Normally, you have classes which manage their own data. If an object needs some data which it doesn't manage, you pass it as a parameter.

So, pass the temperature as a parameter. Explicit is better than implicit.

You mentioned that you have a class representing `Neurons`. I assume you meant `Neuron`, but it would also be good to have a `Neurons` class which keeps them all together. It can have a temperature which it applies to all the `Neuron` calculations.